# How to Immediately (automatically) Link to Another Page

Tags: html

I have an web address *rush.rocksolidpromotion.com* (which is an empty page now) but the content is on the address *rush.rocksolidpromotion.com/rush/home.html* So how can I put a link on the first address *rush.rocksolidpromotion.com* that can automatically send the user to the page that has the content?

Comment: Return an HTTP redirect response (look at the HTTP 300 status code family depending on which redirect you actually need). You _can_ do this with HTML but you really should do this at the http level.

Comment: That other question (How to redirect from an HTML page?) looks useful also. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url='http://rush.rocksolidpromotion.com/rush/home.html'" />

<script>window.location.replace('http://rush.rocksolidpromotion.com/rush/home.html')</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this in the `head` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=rush.rocksolidpromotion.com/rush/home.html">
```

You should also use JavaScript in case the browser ignores `content 0`.  Also a header redirect if you're on a php page.

Comment: @toothbrush Thanks for the answers guys. I'll check them out tomorrow to see if they work :)